# EntityFramework SQLQuery Dynamic Type at Runtime

Tags: sql, entity-framework, dynamic, entity-framework-4

Im just wondering if there is a way to run a string based SQL query against the dbContext and inspect the objects coming back to give the object a type at runtime. i.e. I will not know the structure of the SQL string being executed until runtime.

Is this possible?

code example:

```
My_DataProvidor.DB.Database.SqlQuery<MyDynamicType>("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER").ToList();
```

OR

```
My_DataProvidor.DB.Database.SqlQuery(MyDynamicType,"SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER").ToList();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Using a micro-ORM framework like Dapper or massive.